# Unresolving external symbol error

Tags: c++

New to C++ programming I am trying to get some open source software running so I can build upon it.
I have 3 *cpp modules.  One contains...

```
const double Qcf[6]= { 1.0, 448.831, 0.64632,0.02832, 28.317,  2.4466};
```

The other two modules make use of this constant and have a reference to it included in their body

```
extern double Qcf[];
```

Each of these modules then has a method/ function
i.e. something like

```
void routine1()
{
double i;
i = 2 * Qcf[1];
}
```

I have built the code and it appears that it has compiled (i.e. the *cpp goes to *obj) but I get 2 error messages.
**LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "double*** Qcf"

Each error pertains to each of the *obj files

(I also get another **LNK1120 Two unresolved externals** error, but I think if I solve the LNK2001 issue this will self correct).

Any advice on how to correct this is appreciated in advance.

Comment: try `extern const double Qcf[6];`

Comment: Thank you @BeyelerStudios.  Seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

`Qcf` is defined as a `const double[]` in one module, and declared as `double[]` in the other. You should declare it const too.

(or [`std::array<double, 6>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of a C-style array, if your compiler supports C++11)